# How to fix Bootstrap 3 Modal + CKEditor 4.4 empty dialogs

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, modal-dialog, ckeditor

I'm using

Twitter Bootstrap v3.0.2 and CKEditor v4.3.2

To reproduce the problem:

Create Modal with CKEditor in it, click on selects (select option like font family) multiple times

Result:

The dialogs with fonts and sizes etc become empty

I was looking to fix this since `$('*').unbind()` worked but I didn't want to loose other bound events

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found out that `$('.ui-widget').unbind()` worked so I created a file called

`bootstrap-ckeditor-fix.js` loaded after `bootstrap.js`

And inside it I overrided the event called `enforceFocus` (which triggers on select click)

```
$.fn.modal.Constructor.prototype.enforceFocus = function() {
    $('.ui-widget').unbind();
};
```

V'oila!

Now the first click on select unbinds the events from only the main modal and it works!